# MSQuery includeTotalCount doesn't work?

Tags: ios, azure, azure-mobile-services

> includeTotalCount
>   Indicates if the Windows Azure Mobile Service should also include the total count of items on the server (not just the count of items returned) with the query results.

but totalCount is alway -1,
here is my code

```
MSQuery *query = [_skinsTable query];
query.predicate = bPredicate;
query.includeTotalCount = YES;
query.fetchOffset = offset;
query.fetchLimit = limit;
[query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {

    //here everything is OK(items, error), but totalCount is -1
}];
```

I have no idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't have any custom scripts in your read operation for your table, it should just work. For example, if you create a new table (called 'test'), and run this code below, its `totalCount` parameter will have the appropriate value (4, in this case).

```
- (IBAction)clickMe:(id)sender {
    MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://YOUR-SERVICE.azure-mobile.net/"
                                                 applicationKey:@"YOUR-KEY"];
    MSTable *table = [client tableWithName:@"test"];
    NSDictionary *item1 = @{@"name":@"Scooby Doo",@"age":@10};
    NSDictionary *item2 = @{@"name":@"Shaggy",@"age":@19};
    NSDictionary *item3 = @{@"name":@"Daphne",@"age":@18};
    NSDictionary *item4 = @{@"name":@"Fred",@"age":@20};
    NSDictionary *item5 = @{@"name":@"Velma",@"age":@21};
    [table insert:item1 completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {
        [table insert:item2 completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {
            [table insert:item3 completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {
                [table insert:item4 completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {
                    [table insert:item5 completion:^(NSDictionary *item, NSError *error) {
                        MSQuery *query = [table query];
                        NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age > 15"];
                        query.predicate = bPredicate;
                        query.includeTotalCount = YES;
                        query.fetchLimit = 3;
                        query.fetchOffset = 0;
                        [query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Items: %@", items);
                            NSLog(@"TotalCount: %d", totalCount);
                        }];
                    }];
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

One good way to check that the request and response are the ones expected to get the inlineCount to work is to use a custom filter which logs the request and responses. Define a new interface as the one below:

```
@interface FPLoggingFilter : NSObject<MSFilter>

@end

@implementation FPLoggingFilter

- (void)handleRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request next:(MSFilterNextBlock)next response:(MSFilterResponseBlock)response {
    NSLog(@"Request: %@", request);
    next(request, ^(NSHTTPURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", response);
        NSString *respBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response body: %@", respBody);
        response(resp, data, error);
    });
}

@end
```

And change the code in the inner-most block to use that:

```
MSClient *filteredClient = [client clientWithFilter:[FPLoggingFilter new]];
MSTable *filteredTable = [filteredClient tableWithName:@"test"];
MSQuery *query = [filteredTable query];
NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"age > 15"];
query.predicate = bPredicate;
query.includeTotalCount = YES;
query.fetchLimit = 3;
query.fetchOffset = 0;
[query readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *items, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Items: %@", items);
    NSLog(@"TotalCount: %d", totalCount);
}];
```

Now, if you run this code, you should see in the logs that the request has a `$inlinecount=allpages` query string parameter. And the response isn't a simple array of objects. Instead, it's an object with two properties: results and count:

```
{
    "results" : [
        {"id":2,"age":19,"name":"Shaggy"},
        {"id":3,"age":18,"name":"Daphne"},
        {"id":4,"age":20,"name":"Fred"}
    ],
    "count":4
}
```

That's the reponse returned by a table without any custom scripts (or when the script doesn't override the response) when it receives a request with the `$inlinecount=allpages` parameter. Now, if we change the read script to change something not in that format (for example, by returning only the items (and not the object with the total count property):

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    var result = [];
    result.push({ id: 1, name: 'Scooby Doo', age: 10 });
    result.push({ id: 1, name: 'Shaggy', age: 19 });
    request.respond(200, results);
}
```

Then the client won't be able to retrieve that value, simply because it's not present in the HTTP response.

**Update after comment**: If you want to go through the results and alter them before sending the response to the client, while still preserving the `includeTotalCount` functionality, you have two options: either change the results array directly, and call `request.respond()` (with no parameters) - which will send the (modified) result of the read operation; or if you want to do some more extensive changes in the results you can get the `totalCount` property from the results array (yes, a number property will be tacked to the array; this is JavaScript, after all, where all goes) if the `$inlinecount=allpages` parameter was sent in the query string of the request. With that value you can format the response appropriately, as shown below.

```
function read(query, user, request) {
    request.execute({
        success: function(results) {
            results.forEach(function(result, index) {
                result.newValue = index;
            });

            //request.respond(); - this should work.

            var totalCount = results.totalCount;
            if (totalCount) {
                request.respond(200, { count: totalCount, results: results });
            } else {
                request.respond(200, results);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @carlosfigueira, that's exactly the case (me and @sheraza work on that problem together). 

Custom script does indeed change the results, but we need to change it (we are adding one field to each row). Can you please advise, how can we do it, without spoiling `count`? 

Can we somehow refer to the actual response, or that particular property (`count`)? Or do we need to run `SELECT count(*) FROM our_table` and construct response manually?

Comment: If all you want to do is to change some property in the response, you can call `request.respond()` and the modifications should be honored. Or if you want to do some additional processing and want the (original) value of the total count, you can get the `totalCount` property from the results array. See the updated answer for an example.